# Unable to connect to websites which donot start with www

Tags: internet, hot-spot

I have created hotspot from my Andriod mobile and using Internet on laptop Windows 7 but I'm unable to connect to websites which don't start with `www.`.

The error:

> If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web

**Should the settings be done on mobile or laptop? What should I change?**

Note I am using mobile data. Websites starting with `www.` are working fine. The problem doesn't occur on my phone. Also everything is OK when my laptop uses LAN.

Mobile(alone with data) and laptop(alone with LAN) works fine , it is only when mobile hotspot is used in laptop, i am not able to access websites which don't start with www.

Comment: Can you access the same websites in your phone's web browser?

Comment: Not all web sites allow access without the www. Sometimes it is because of dns, and sometimes becuase of the way the web server is configured.

Comment: @CelticWarrior yes able to access on mobile and also on laptop with Lan network websites without www.

Comment: @Doug Smythies what settings to be done to access websites without www. On laptop using hotspot of mobile data

Comment: If the website doesn't allow it, or isn't setup for it, there is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: @Doug Smythies i am able to access that website like askubuntu.com from my mobile but not from laptop..also from Lan network ..but not through mobile hotspot

Comment: O.K. that was not obvious, at least to me, from all that you have said. You should edit your question with very detailed examples.

Comment: @Doug Smythies all websites having www. At start after https are working but websites which donot start with www. Are not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1)Go Wireless Network connections Status.
>
> 2)Properties
>
> 3)Networking
>
> 4)Configure

After doing this there was error DHCP not there , I gave auto fix in windows.
And all websites started working.

Answer (score 0):

That is determined by the DNS entries set up with the web site.

For instance, you can get to mine at http://calttc.net or just calttc.net

Also, you can get to COX's speed test at http://fast.com or just fast.com

Google doesn't require the www.  But a lot of web sites do.  It all depends on how they were set up.

So there is nothing wrong with your computer.